# Eve: how to use different endpoints to access the same collection with different filters

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I have an [Eve](https://python-eve.org/) app publishing a simple read-only (GET) interface. It is interfacing a MongoDB collection called `centroids`, which has documents like:

```
[
{
  "name":"kachina chasmata",
  "location":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[-116.65,-32.6]
  },
  "body":"ariel"
},
{
  "name":"hokusai",
  "location":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[16.65,57.84]
  },
  "body":"mercury"
},
{
  "name":"cañas",
  "location":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[89.86,-31.188]
  },
  "body":"mars"
},
{
  "name":"anseris cavus",
  "location":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[95.5,-29.708]
  },
  "body":"mars"
}
]
```

Currently, (Eve) settings declare a `DOMAIN` as follows:

```py
crater = {
    'hateoas': False,
    'item_title': 'crater centroid',
    'url': 'centroid/<regex("[\w]+"):body>/<regex("[\w ]+"):name>',
    'datasource': {
        'projection': {'name': 1, 'body': 1, 'location.coordinates': 1}
    }
}

DOMAIN = {
    'centroids': crater,
}
```

Which will successfully answer to requests of the form `http://hostname/centroid/<body>/<name>`. Inside MongoDB this represents a query like: `db.centroids.find({body:<body>, name:<name>})`.

What I would like to do also is to offer an endpoint for *all* the documents of a given `body`. I.e., a request to `http://hostname/centroids/<body>` would answer the list of all documents with `body==<body>`: `db.centroids.find({body:<body>})`.

*How do I do that?*

I gave a shot by including a list of rules to the `DOMAIN` key `centroids` (the name of the database collection) like below,

```py
crater = {
...
}

body = {
    'item_title': 'body craters',
    'url': 'centroids/<regex("[\w]+"):body>'
}

DOMAIN = {
    'centroids': [crater, body],
}
```

but didn't work...

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

Comment: Have you tried `http://hostname/centroids?where={"body": <body>}`?

Comment: @gcw Yes, indeed that works out of the box if I keep the default settings, _i.e._, `DOMAIN = {'centroids': {}}`. That being the case, I could use `http://hostname/centroids?where={"body":"mars","name":"cañas"}`. The key point here is that I want to offer to my user a clean interface, made by simple, db agnostic path endpoints. For instance: `http://hostname/centroids/mars` or `http://hostname/centroids/mars/cañas`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I was assuming the *keys* in the `DOMAIN` structure was directly related to the *collection* Eve was querying. That is true for the default settings, but it can be adjusted inside the resources [datasource](https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/config.html#datasource).

I figured that out while handling an analogous situation as that of the question: I wanted to have an endpoint `hostname/bodies` listing all the (unique) values for `body` in the `centroids` collection. To that, I needed to set an [aggregation](https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#aggregation) to it.

The following settings give me exactly that ;)

```
centroids = {
    'item_title': 'centroid',
    'url': 'centroid/<regex("[\w]+"):body>/<regex("[\w ]+"):name>',
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'centroids',
        'projection': {'name': 1, 'body': 1, 'location.coordinates': 1}
    }
}

bodies = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'centroids',
        'aggregation': {
            'pipeline': [
                {"$group": {"_id": "$body"}},
            ]
        },
    }
}

DOMAIN = {
    'centroids': centroids,
    'bodies': bodies
}
```

- The endpoint, for example, `http://127.0.0.1:5000/centroid/mercury/hokusai` give me the `name`, `body`, and `coordinates` of `mercury/hokusai`.
- And the endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:5000/bodies`, the list of unique values for `body` in `centroids`.

Beautiful. Thumbs up to Eve!